# How to open and update WPF window by threading

Tags: wpf, multithreading, window

I have Two WPF window Window1.xaml and window2.xaml.
In window2.xaml.cs i have one function which does some complex calculation and display intermediate resuls on a TextBlock.

Now What i want.
by clicking on button of Window1.xaml i want to open Window2.xaml as a dialog box and want to execute complex function of windows2.xaml.

If i call complex button on Window2.xaml' load event then dilog box apear after execution of complex function.

How to do this by Threading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not open the window in a thread. Once you've opened Window2, start a thread for the complex function in the `Window2.Loaded` event handler. This will leave your UI undisturbed.

Comment: private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {            
            Thread t = new Thread(ComplexFunction);
            t.Start();                        
        }

and in 
ComplexFunction()
{
// doing something
UpdateStatus("adasd");
// doing something
UpdateStatus("dsad");
}
 
It gives runtime error.
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it
UpdateStatus(string status)
{
StatusText.AppendText(status + "\r");
}

Comment: @Jeevan Bhatt: If you're accessing any element created in UIThread then you may need to ask the dispatcher to do the favour for you. `myDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => { // Code that accessess UIElement }));` where myDispatcher is a reference to Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher Set this before calling the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Opening a Window in a thread that is not UI thread is not recommended at all. You can open a popup window using `Show()` (modeless) method or `ShowDialog()` (modal) method. In Window2's load method, you can start a new thread which does a complex operation and once it is done with the operation, it can show a dialog.

Now, while in a different thread than UI thread, if you want to show any UI (dialogs, windows) or change existing UI (textblock, etc), you must use [`Dispatcher.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx) method.